# How can I use NIB loaded UIView in tableView viewForHeaderInSection without having a performance hit

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm implementing tableView viewForHeaderInSection where I return a nib loaded UITableViewCell.

I've simplified it for the purpose of this question.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView* header = [CellFactoryController newSectionHeader];
    header.text = "Some Text Depending on the section"
    return header;

}
```

Unfortunatly this is very slow because I sometimes have 50+ headers which all get loaded from nib all at once when the table draws , even though those headers are not in view.

Is there any realistic way of me being able to clone UIViews and thus clone the header in this example?  Or is the only way for me to just create the headers UIView hard coded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the doco on the [UINib class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) the other night and it was talking about how it caches the nibs internal structure so repeated requests execute faster. That might be a suitable option for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don’t know if you still need an answer to this question, but… what the heck. Let’s do this. I’m going to make some assumptions, but if you’re having performance problems the only way to really solve this is going to be to test it, and without more knowledge of your views’ complexity, we can’t really get reliable metrics. So I’m going to assume that you’ve tried a few things and throw something out there that you maybe haven’t tried.

When you load a view out of a nib, it unarchives it from a file. *If* that loading is happening 50 times, that could go a long way towards your performance problems. So what else can we do? Well, in your table view controller class, make a new instance variable of type `NSData`. Then, in your `-init` method (or other designated initializer), load a view in from a property list:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // Other initialization code.

        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyView"
                                                             ofType:@"plist"];
        myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }

    return self;
}
```

OK, so you have this property list loaded into an `NSData`. Now, the rest should be clear:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *view = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];

    return view;
}
```

My goal here was to keep the fully-instantiated view in memory the whole time. But then I thought, “how is he going to create that plist?” So I modified it a bit. Instead of loading the data from a file, create your view in code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView;

    if (myData == nil) {
        headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        // Configure your view, but only that part that isn’t customized.

        myData = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:headerView] copy];
    } else {
        headerView = [NSKeyedArchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
    }

    // Now customize the view for your particular section.

    return headerView;
}
```

That should give you the flexibility of creating the view in code, but hopefully also keep it in memory and cache it for you. Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

You could, potentially, break up your views into separate .xib files to speed loading, but (as you said) your best bet is probably going to be to create those views procedurally.  Outside of quickie sample code, .xib files are generally reserved for very high-level layout of containers needed for an entire app or a full-screen view.  The layout and drawing detail-oriented elements— such as the cells, headers, and footers in table views— is typically better handled procedurallly.